# Why getting a cookie isn't working?

Tags: javascript, dom

This is driving me crazy! I have a cookie that was set from a response header that contains the sessionid. The cookie is visable in the dev tools in Chrome and in Firefox, but `document.cookie` returns an empty string.

The cookie looks like this:

```
Name: sessionid
Value: 123456789
Domain: app
Path: /
Expires: Session
Secure: No
```

The url I'm hitting is `http://app/`

Any ideas on why this I can't access this cookie through the DOM api?

Comment: Is it an `httpOnly` cookie? They are not visible through JS.

Comment: Can you include the response header and the code you use to access the cookie?

Comment: @loganfsmyth yup that was it. My googlefu has failed me. If you want to post that as an answer I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies that are marked `httpOnly` are not accessible from JavaScript in order to mitigate attacks that would steal session keys via XSS. The cookie you are looking for is probably marked with that.